# parameter of onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, parameter-passing

I am trying to build a string like this:

```
"<a><p onclick='showDialog(" + b + ")'>Clicca qui!</p></a>"
```

However in this way I cannot pass the parameter.

The error is: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

b is a string parameter.

So, how should I alter this?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of the `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string `b` seems to contains parenthesis.

You might want to add some extra quote around your string :

```
"<a><p onclick='showDialog(\"" + b + "\")'>Clicca qui!</p></a>"
```

Comment: If you could mark this as the answer, it would be awesome ! ;)